# How to profile PySide2 + QML in QtCreator?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt-creator, pyside2

I have a PySide2 application, which uses QML to display the user interface. The application works from the command line. I can also launch it as well as debug it in QtCreator. However, when I try to run QmlProfiler, I see the following error:

```
:-1: error: /home/username/code/project/venv/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'ljsdebugger=file:/tmp/QtCreator-kVUFuF/qtcreator-freesocket.XgLEKq,block,services:CanvasFrameRate,EngineControl,DebugMessages,DebugTranslation' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ljsdebugger=file:/tmp/QtCreator-kVUFuF/qtcreator-freesocket')
```

I checked project's kit settings and it is using all the defaults. I could not find any relevant articles/discussions with this error message on the web. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solving this involves two steps:

1. Make the application debugging enabled

Add the line before QApplication is instantated:

```
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlDebuggingEnabler

debug = QQmlDebuggingEnabler()
```

2. Connect it to the QML Profiler

run the application with the command line parameter: `-qmljsdebugger=port:10002,block` with the port of your choice. Then go to Analyze>QML Profiler (Attach to Waiting Application) and choose the port you started the program with:
[image]

This successfully connected the program to the QML Profiler.

Answer (score -1):

```
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlDebuggingEnabler

debug = QQmlDebuggingEnabler()
```

it also useful in pyside6 , tks bro @WhiteStork

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).