# Debugging pyside, QML, JS project in Qt-Creator

Tags: qt-creator, pyside2

I try to get started with Qt pyside with QML and JS using Qt-Creator IDE. Since the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/debugging/qtcreator/qtcreator.html) remains vague about debugging capabilities of Qt-Creator I would like to have confirmed, that my debugging experience is expected behaviour.

- in .py breakpoints work, but print("some string") doesn't print to application output.
- in .qml breakpoint's don't work, neither does console.debug("some string") print anything
- in .js breakpoint's don't work, neither does console.debug("some string") print

Is this: *Qt Creator does not support mixed mode debugging* ? Is PyCharm more suitable?

System: Python 3.8.2,Pyside2 (installed via pip),Qt Creator 4.13.3 Based on Qt 5.15.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it need mixed mode debug.I use PyCharm and Qt Creator.
You can use PyCharm to show the python log and debug .py , use qt creator to show the js log and debug .qml at the sometime.

First you need Enable QML , [see](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-qml.html)

Next run .py on PyCharm and connect qml port on Qt Creator, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64117399/13099363)

Final , you can debug .py and .qml

My System: Python 3.9.7,Pyside6,Qt Creator 7.0.1 Based on Qt 6.2.3